# JQuery Slideshow only works on the most recent post. Need it to work on most recent posts on homepage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, slideshow

Complete newbie here.

I need the following slideshow to work for all recent posts on the homepage (wordpress). Currently, it only works on the most recent post (latest post).

Here's my code in content.php:

```
            <div id="textslider"> 

            <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
                <p style="position: relative; left: -50%; border: none;"> 
                    <?php echo get_field('slide1'); ?> 
                </p>
            </div>

            <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
                <p style="position: relative; left: -50%; border: none;"> 
                    <?php echo get_field('slide2'); ?> 
                </p>
            </div>

            <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
                <p style="position: relative; left: -50%; border: none;"> 
                    <?php echo get_field('slide3'); ?> 
                </p>

            </div>

            </div>
```

Here's my js code in header.php (Jonathan Snook's code):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">
<script>

$('#textslider > div:gt(0)').hide();

    setInterval(function() { 
    $('#textslider > div:first').fadeOut(500)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#textslider');
},  3000);

</script>
```

PS: I know that Snook has multiple slideshow on the same page version but I can't get that to work at all. And for the above, changing the textslider from ID to class makes none of the slideshow to loop at all. Please help.

Thanks

UPDATE: 
@Reddy Thank you for getting back to me. This is what the homepage looks like:

[yulius Homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/givzl.png)

Test post 12's text slideshow works just fine (slides: "1","2","3"). Test Post 10 also has a text slideshow (slides: 'some text 1', 'some text 2', 'some text 3') but it doesn't work, as you can see, the words stack on top of one another.

This is the code for TEST POST 12 (most recent post):

```
     <article id="post-78" class="post-78 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized post-grid">

 <style type="text/css">
            .post-78 { background-color: #000000 !important; }

</style>
 <div class="post-cover post-cover-78 stag-image--none"></div>

 <a href="http://myweb.com/test-post-12/" class="post-cover-link"></a>

 <div class="post-content">
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title">

            <a href="http://myweb.com/test-post-12/" rel="bookmark">
            <span class="entry-title-primary">test post 12</span> <span     class="entry-subtitle">subtitle bottom</span>                               </a>

            <p class="entry-content">subtitle top</p>

            <div id="textslider"> 

            <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
                <p style="position: relative; left: -50%; border: none;"> 
                    1 
                </p>
            </div>

            <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
                <p style="position: relative; left: -50%; border: none;"> 
                    2 
                </p>
            </div>

            <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
                <p style="position: relative; left: -50%; border: none;"> 
                    3 
                </p>

            </div>

            </div> 
        </h1>

    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <footer class="entry-meta">
        <span class="posted-on"><a href="http://myweb.com/test-post-     12/" title="4:06 pm" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date published" datetime="2016-03-02T16:06:39+00:00">March 2, 2016</time><time class="updated" datetime="2016-03-03T16:00:26+00:00">March 3, 2016</time></a></span><span class="reading-time">1 minute read</span><span class="byline">by <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="http://myweb.com/author/yulius/">yulius</a></span></span>                           </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->


        </div>
    </article>
```

This is the code for Test Post 11:

```
     <article id="post-65" class="post-65 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized post-grid">

<style type="text/css">
            .post-65 { background-color: #000000 !important; }

</style>
```

```
<a href="http://myweb.com/test-post-11/" class="post-cover-link"></a>

<div class="post-content">
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title">

            <a href="http://myweb.com/test-post-11/" rel="bookmark">
            <span class="entry-title-primary">test post 11</span> <span class="entry-subtitle">"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..." "There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."</span>                               </a>

            <p class="entry-content">yoohoo</p>

            <div id="textslider"> 

            <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
                <p style="position: relative; left: -50%; border: none;"> 

                </p>
            </div>

            <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
                <p style="position: relative; left: -50%; border: none;"> 

                </p>
            </div>

            <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
                <p style="position: relative; left: -50%; border: none;"> 

                </p>

            </div>

            </div> 
        </h1>

    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <footer class="entry-meta">
        <span class="posted-on"><a href="http://myweb.com/test-post-11/" title="3:12 pm" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date published" datetime="2016-03-01T15:12:55+00:00">March 1, 2016</time><time class="updated" datetime="2016-03-02T15:41:23+00:00">March 2, 2016</time></a></span><span class="reading-time">1 minute read</span><span class="byline">by <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="http://myweb.com/author/yulius/">yulius</a></span></span>                 </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->


        </div>
    </article>
```

This is the code for Test POST 10 (This one also has a slideshow but as you can see, the texts stack on top of one another and the slideshow does not work at all):

```
     <article id="post-63" class="post-63 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized post-grid">

<style type="text/css">
            .post-63 { background-color: #000000 !important; }

</style>
```

```
<a href="http://myweb.com/test-post-10/" class="post-cover-link"></a>

<div class="post-content">
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title">

            <a href="http:/myweb.com/test-post-10/" rel="bookmark">
            <span class="entry-title-primary">test post 10</span> <span class="entry-subtitle">am super cool</span>                             </a>

            <p class="entry-content">i am cool</p>

            <div id="textslider"> 

            <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
                <p style="position: relative; left: -50%; border: none;"> 
                    &quot;the coolest of all cakes!!!&quot; 
                </p>
            </div>

            <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
                <p style="position: relative; left: -50%; border: none;"> 
                    &quot;super good&quot; 
                </p>
            </div>

            <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
                <p style="position: relative; left: -50%; border: none;"> 
                    &quot;unbelievable&quot; 
                </p>

            </div>

            </div> 
        </h1>

    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <footer class="entry-meta">
        <span class="posted-on"><a href="http://myweb.com/test-post-10/" title="3:12 pm" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date published" datetime="2016-03-01T15:12:19+00:00">March 1, 2016</time><time class="updated" datetime="2016-03-03T18:02:40+00:00">March 3, 2016</time></a></span><span class="reading-time">1 minute read</span><span class="byline">by <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="http://myweb.com/author/yulius/">yulius</a></span></span>                 </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->


        </div>
    </article>
```

This is the Code for test post 9:

```
     <article id="post-60" class="post-60 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized post-grid">

<style type="text/css">
            .post-60 { background-color: #000000 !important; }

</style>
```

```
<a href="http://myweb.com/test-post-9/" class="post-cover-link"></a>

<div class="post-content">
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title">

            <a href="http://myweb.com/test-post-9/" rel="bookmark">
            <span class="entry-title-primary">test post 9</span> <span class="entry-subtitle">oblique is Cool</span>                                </a>

            <p class="entry-content"></p>

            <div id="textslider"> 

            <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
                <p style="position: relative; left: -50%; border: none;"> 

                </p>
            </div>

            <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
                <p style="position: relative; left: -50%; border: none;"> 

                </p>
            </div>

            <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
                <p style="position: relative; left: -50%; border: none;"> 

                </p>

            </div>

            </div> 
        </h1>

    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <footer class="entry-meta">
        <span class="posted-on"><a href="http://myweb.com/test-post-9/" title="3:11 pm" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date published" datetime="2016-03-01T15:11:49+00:00">March 1, 2016</time><time class="updated" datetime="2016-03-02T14:42:36+00:00">March 2, 2016</time></a></span><span class="reading-time">1 minute read</span><span class="byline">by <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="http://myweb.com/author/yulius/">yulius</a></span></span>                  </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->


        </div>
    </article>
```

Thanks again. Sorry about the split code blocks for posts 11, 10 and 9, not quite sure how to fix that.

Comment: what is the difference between your `all recent posts` and ` most recent post `

Comment: The most recent post lies at the top most part of the homepage, and takes up the entire width of the viewport. Later recent posts lie beneath it. Some of them takes up 50% of the viewport width, others 100%. But I wrote the codes above myself, they are not part of the theme. Here's a video of the theme: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lL0N034Oecc . I intend to add a text slideshow beneath all the post titles, and the outcome is like what I explained in my opening post.

Comment: Ok got it, Can you post the HTML of your  all recent div and most recent div.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

```
$('.textslider').each(function(){
    $(this).children('div:gt(0)').hide();
}); 

$('.textslider').each(function(){
    var parentDiv = $(this);
    //alert(parentDiv);
    setInterval(function() {    
        parentDiv.children('div:first').fadeOut(500)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .end()
            .appendTo(parentDiv);
    },  3000, parentDiv);
});
```

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for but... well hope it helps bringing some light onto you problem:

```
$('#textslider > div').each(function(){
    $(this).children('p:gt(0)').hide();
}); 

$('#textslider > div').each(function(){
    var parentDiv = $(this);
    //alert(parentDiv);
    setInterval(function() {    
        parentDiv.children('p:first').fadeOut(500)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .end()
            .appendTo(parentDiv);
    },  3000, parentDiv);
});
```

My html (divs...)

```
      <div id="textslider">
            <div>
                <p>text1</p>
                <p>text2</p>
                <p>text3</p>
                <p>text4</p>
                <p>text5</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>texta</p>
                <p>textb</p>
                <p>textc</p>
                <p>textd</p>
                <p>texte</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>t1</p>
                <p>t2</p>
                <p>t3</p>
                <p>t4</p>
                <p>t5</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

They all "animate" at the same time.

Comment: thank you for your answer. What I am looking for is javascript or jquery that can drive one set of DIV containing several slides for every individual posts in the homepage (containing all the recent posts). Not jquery or javascript driving many set of DIVs at once for one single post.Could there be a difference?

Comment: You have more than one element with ID="textslider"? because if you do, the `.appendTo('#textslider');` will work only with the first instance of it... and because of the `style="position: absolute;...` all the text get displayed one on top of the other.

I change the `id="textslider"` to `class="textslider"` and because there could be more than one element I use the `$(".textslider").each(function(){...});` 

like this I edit above.